# How much windscreen washer fluid does a Alfa Romeo Giulia (2017 model) take?

Tags: windshield-washer, alfa-romeo

I need to top up the windscreen washer fluid on my Alfa Giulia (2017 model).
Normally the workshop does that when the car is in for maintenance, but this time I have run dry before the scheduled visit to the workshop.

I have no idea of the size of the reservoir.
I need to buy anti-freeze (either pre-mixed or as an additive) and how much depends on how much fluid the reservoir will take.
The owners manual doesn't say how much.
I can't eyeball the reservoir either as it is buried quite deep inside the engine bay. (From what I can see the filler-pipe alone would take at least a liter.)

Does anyone know how much fluid would roughly be needed ?

Comment: You never have to top off the windscreen washing water between maintenances? You either have a very clean environment or you do a lot of maintenance.

Comment: @AndreKR Twice or 3 times per year before COVID. I used to drive 1200 to 1500 km per week. And relatively clean. No dirt roads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just go for broke. I don't know what size of jugs you can purchase where you're at, but you can get more than you need, fill up the washer tank, then keep what's left over for the next time you run out between maintenance visits. The washer fluid won't go bad, so there's no issue just storing the leftovers. Here in the States I buy gallons at a time. My wife goes nuts with the stuff, so I keep way more than I need on hand for when she runs out.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty big reservoir as it turned out to be.
Got a 20L pre-mixed jerrycan and used almost half of it.
About 8 liters (that's about 2 US gallons).

Answer (score 2):

Probably 2 to 4 liters, but it's a guess.

Buy a liter of windshield washer fluid. Pour it in. If the level isn't as high as you wish, add another liter. Repeat until the level in the reservoir is where you want it.

At least here in the US, washer fluid is inexpensive. I keep a gallon jug (~4 liters) under my workbench.

Comment: It is pretty cheap here in the Netherlands as well (normally) but due to the weird way the Covid lockdown measures are implemented here I can't easily buy it anywhere. All shops/retail are closed except for supermarkets and food (or pharmacy) retail. Even petrol stations can't sell shop items. They are only allowed to sell petrol now. Car workshops can do service/repairs (and whatever parts/consumables are part of that), but can't sell me a jug of fluid separately. So I have to pay them for labor just to put it in and the minimum labor charge is half an hour. Too silly for words...

Comment: continued... As I live close to the Belgium border I guess I just drive to Belgium tomorrow. There all shops are open as normal. Just need to wear a face-mask.

Comment: @Tonny It's not really that bad. Just order it online and pick it up at a store (that's allowed no matter what you buy).